# get images from post and make a zip

Tags: images, gallery

here is what i have so far.

```
  function zip_gallery()
  {
      global $post;
      $images = get_children(array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_mime_type' => 'image', ));

      if ($images) {
          $save = $post->post_title;

          $zip = new ZipArchive;
          if ($zip->open($save . '.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
              foreach ($images as $image) {
                  $file = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID, 'full', false, false);
                  $filename = pathinfo($file);
                  $zip->addFile($file, $filename);
              }

              $zip->close();
          }
      }
  }
```

can someone shed some light on what im doing wrong.

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ZipArchive->addFile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php) method expects local path to file, while [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) returns URL. You need to build local path for file from URL or in other way.

Comment: is there a plugin which does this?

Comment: @user3047 not that I know, but I hadn't looked...

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? This way?

Comment: @user3047 I merely pointed out obvious error in code back then, I had not tried to implement and test this.